# Breath reducing while training - is it effective?

Tags: training, exercise, breathing, endurance

Recently, I've seen a short story on TV about training with mask - to reduce breath. There was a guy, punching the bag for rounds, with mask on his face. Mask looked like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXr2kaCk3EU).

I said OK, and replaced some of my running with running breathing only with nose - and it was much more harder of course. However, after about a month, I didn't notice any boost.

Are those masks really effective?

Comment: This isn't about martial arts - so is probably more appropriate on physical fitness.

Comment: @Collett89, understand you, I'm really sorry. TV story was with guy punching a bag, so I implicitly understand this question applicable here. I don't have enough rights to move it - but if you want to close - I'll support you and add my vote to close too.

Comment: [Skeptic](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) might be an even better fit. Although, I am happy for this to stay here provided it was more focused on martial arts instead of a general "does it work"?

Comment: @Sardathrion-ReinstateMonica, thank you, very glad to see such warm appreciating.

Comment: This has been asked on martial arts, fitness, medical science, so it would be marked as duplicate. The basic answer is "no", except to improve intercostal muscle function. It would make a great question for skeptics, provided it meets their rather exacting standards. :)

Comment: @JohnP, understand, thank you! I've searched a bit but didn't found those question. For now - problem solved - that does not work.)